# A word problem, selling cakes and finding the maximum

Tags: derivatives

A school class is saving money for a classtrip and therefore sell cakes.
The function $f(x)=x(x-25)(x-15)$ describes how much money the class saves
in total for selling cakes.

f(x) is the total amount of sum in dollars and x is what they earn per
cake. Their teachers said that they cant sell a cake for more than 15 dollars
but not more. How much money should they ask per/cake to earn as much as possible?

This is what I did: 
$$x(x^2-15x-25x+375)$$
$$x(x^2-40x+375)$$
$$x^3-40x^2+375x$$ Then derivate $= 3x^2-80x+375$. Then $3x^2-80x+375=0$ to find maximum but I cant divide $80/3$, what more can I do to answer the question?

Comment: $x$ is what they earn per cake, or how much they sell a cake for? I mean selling price or profit?

Comment: x is how much they sell a cake for

Comment: okay. one more clarification "**cant sell** a cake for more than 15 dollars but not more" Is that a typo?

Comment: you meant, '**can sell**...' instead? So the maximum they are allowed to charge is \$15 right?

Comment: The teacher doesn't want the kids to ask the customers more than 15 dollars

Comment: ok :) thanks...

Comment: Then I think the children doesn't have to listen to the teacher and can ask more for the cakes?

Comment: actually no sorry. I deleted my comment. I miscalculated. I am posting an answer.

Comment: done. does that work for you? :)

Answer (score 0):

So we have a function $f(x) = x(x-15)(x-25)$. We need to maximize this function under the constraint that $x \le 15$. Obviously for $x\le0$ $f(x)$ is negative so our constraints are, $0\le x\le15$.

Now, consider $f(x) = x^3 -40x^2 + 375x \implies f'(x) = 3x^2 - 80x + 375$

We want to find a root of $f'(x)$, i.e, solve for $f'(x)=0$, such that $0\le x\le 15$.

Applying the quadratic formula,

$$x = \frac{80 \pm \sqrt{6400 - 4500}}{6}$$

Simplifying this becomes, $$x = \frac{40 - 5\sqrt{19}}{3}$$ and $$f(x) = \frac{250}{27}\left(28 + 19\sqrt{19}\right)$$

This is the maximum value. I omitted the calculation, I think you can do that yourself?

Comment: Yes, do I only have to calculate 250/27 and can I skip 28 + 19... or do I have to multiply them both?

Comment: You have to calculate $250/27$ and $28 + 19\sqrt{19}$. And multiply the two results. In case approximate values will do, $f(x)=1026$ at $x=6$. The absolute maximum for $f(x)$ is around $1026.1$. So I think the approximation is good enough?

Comment: Yes, thanks for you effort and time! Very kind of you.

Comment: I am very happy to help. You can 'accept' my answer if it is good enough.

Comment: Ok, I will when I register

Comment: Oh, SE now allows non registered users to have assign names? I didn't know that. Anyway bye now. Feel free to post a question again, in case you need help. :)